# Error while setting up Git

Tags: git, git-bash

I was tasked to setup Git on my machine, but I keep on getting this error when trying to open Git Bash and I can't proceed. I have also tried using 64-bit and 32-bit, neither have worked. I have also tried getting the cygwin.dll that the error message says. Please help!

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bj8zH.jpg)

Comment: Please copy and paste the error output into the question rather than linking to a screenshot, as it's much easier to read directly in the question!

Comment: It's pretty long, please refer here: http://freetexthost.com/z1n50axyhk